# How to implement Cancel with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JavaScript and jQuery to build a pretty complex UI -- it has dropdowns, buttons, elements that are jQuery plugins, etc. At the bottom of the UI, there are two buttons Ok and Cancel. My question is about Cancel -- is there any *easy* way to reset the UI to the original state.

One idea I had was to use $.extend to create a deep copy of my UI, make all changes to the copy, and then "commit" the copy using .html() of the container div if Ok was clicked. Does it sound feasible?

Is there a better way to implement "Cancel" functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: Make a `defaultValue` property/method, so you can say `myThingy.value = myThingy.defaultValue`?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by cancel. Isn't it easier to just reload the page if you want to go back to the original state on page load?

Comment: The "easiest" way to reset the UI to its original state is to refresh the page.

Comment: One way would be to structure your application so that a single function is used to initialize the UI. Then to reset it, you can call that function again. (Note that you'll probably have the build the DOM from this function--you won't be able to stick your UI in your markup unless you use something like [_.template](http://underscorejs.org/#template))

Comment: Are you using `input` elements? Can you post a sample of what you have so far (here, and as a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/))?

Comment: I cannot refresh the page because it's a sub-UI on the client side -- a settings popup for a chart. The settings UI includes INPUT elements but also custom jQuery plugins. All need to be reset if a user clicks Cancel. The INPUTs can be reset by FORM.RESET, but not visibility/enabled state of elements or custom jQuery plugins. Am I thinking about this wrong? Thanks.

Comment: For usability, a "Cancel" button should not reset the dialog - it should close it without prompting for confirmation.  That is easier for you and friendlier for the user.

Comment: Yeah. I may have to re-work what I have -- currently, the settings UI is "connected" to the chart in that I don't destroy the UI after the host dialog is closed, so that if a dialog is re-opened, all the information about the chart -- axes, legends, chart type -- are up to date. By, I guess I will have to change it, so the settings UI refreshes from chart on each dialog open -- otherwise, it's too hard to cancel changes. Can't have my cake and eat it too :).